# Get User's Last Activity Time from Onelogin GetUser API

Tags: onelogin

I am looking to get the user's last activity/accessed timestamp from Onelogin Get User API.
But I cannot find the field in the API documentation.
https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/2/users/get-user

Any suggestion on how can I retrieve that information from Onelogin using the get user API.

Comment: OneLogin API has a section on extracting data for reporting: [https://developers.onelogin.com/quickstart/reporting](https://developers.onelogin.com/quickstart/reporting), below `Export user details to CSV` it has the list of attributes you can access for a user, one of them being `last_login`.